# Can this question be salvaged?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I read what I thought was an interesting [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391798/112436), which got what I thought was an answer-material comment.  The question had one close vote, but seemed to be in a bit of a gray area.  I edited the question to try to make it less gray, and unsuccessfully invited the commenter to write an answer.  (I would like the information provided in the comment to be preserved and searchable.)  The commenter felt that to answer a poorly posed question would compromise the integrity of the site.  I hesitate to lift the material from his comment and put it in an answer.  First, if I can, I'd like to edit the question, to make it well posed by community standards.

I'd appreciate some help editing the question to bring it better into line with site expectations.

Alternatively, if it's okay in its current form, I'd like some help justifying that the question is well posed.

Comment: 1-The question is not in fact a request for resources. That is plain. Every question on this site could be prepended by 'Is there a reference that answers ...". 2-There's only one close vote, presumably by the person who things it is a resource request. Don't worry until there are 3. 3-Sadly, I suspect the question is a duplicate many times over but search capabilities are not precise enough to look for them.

Comment: @Mitch - Thanks.  // But wasn't it a bang-up answer, couched as a comment?  How can I get the participant to post it as an answer?

Comment: @aparente001 if they're uninterested in posting an answer, feel free to post one your own, giving credits where it's due.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a request for resources, and I suggest migrating it to meta, since we do accommodate such questions here, albeit **rarely**.

Comment: No. The question is asking "what is the preferred way to say this?" All questions include assumed requests for objective substantiation through a reference. Asking for it explicitly doesn't mean it is a general request for a reference.